# SQL Server 2008 returns "Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query"

Tags: php, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to fill a HTML table with some SQL Server 2008 r2 data, the controller (php_sqlsrv) works fine, the tables are filled very well, but when I try to retrieve a 2000 or more rows (maybe less) it crashes and shows this message:

> SQL Error: Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => IMSSP [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP [1] => -59 [code] => -59 [2] => Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query [message] => Memory limit of 10240 KB exceeded for buffered query ))

How can I fix this? Is this a PHP or a sqlsrv  problem? Can I fix this from the SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Can we see your code that does this? Are you trying to hold all of those rows in memory? Can you increase the buffer limit it refers to? I don't know where that is set, but I imagine php.net has docs on it.

Comment: Great. Please add a solution in the box below, so that other people can see how to fix this error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change the setting in php.ini.

Section: sqlsrv

Directive: sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize.

Answer (score 14):

add two lines in php.ini

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
client_buffer_max_kb_size = '50240'
sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize = 50240
```

Comment: If you are using PDO (like for Drupal) you need to have also add 
pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size = 50240

Comment: Thanks!  This really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 14):

You can also change the settings during runtime if you do not require production server to have the php.ini changed (Check if this is applicable with your hosting).

Update the code with following lines:

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M'); // This also needs to be increased in some cases. Can be changed to a higher value as per need)
ini_set('sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize','524288'); // Setting to 512M
ini_set('pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size','524288'); // Setting to 512M - for pdo_sqlsrv
```

To check if your server supports this, try printing the values after setting the above.

```
echo ini_get('memory_limit');
echo ini_get('sqlsrv.ClientBufferMaxKBSize');
echo ini_get('pdo_sqlsrv.client_buffer_max_kb_size');
```

The new values should be the ones we had set in ini_set(). Else, the server does not support runtime configuration changes.

Comment: The best solution, application-based instead of global.